# Best way to optimize (loss-less) thousands of jpgs in a windows folder structure?

Tags: optimization, images

Using Smush.it or Firebug's built-in image optimizer I realize we can reduce the file size of all of our web jpgs. By quite much actually. As we have hundreds of thousands of images, is there any way to batch optimize (and replace) these images using any tool you know of (except the aforementioned as they only operate one by one)? Really don't want to do this manually one by one. :(

Comment: I think you want lossy compression, not lossless compression.

Comment: No, I want loss-less... lossy compression destroys visual image quality and that's a big no-no.

Comment: Firebug's "optimization" was a lossy compression process. For most images it simply reduced the image quality by a small enough amount that people wouldn't notice but the file size shrinks drastically. This is a very noticeable difference in JPEG images with quality levels over 90%.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the ImageMagick utilities from http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

You can use the `convert` utility from ImageMagick along with some simple command-line scripting. You can use a Unix system or Cygwin in Windows

The exact convert command would be `convert -quality 50 in.jpg out.jpg`. Adjust the quality parameter to the desired value. (Note: This is a lossy operation)

The convert utility can also convert to other formats, like PNG, which is lossless.

If you have Unix or bash on Cygwin, the full operation would be:

```
for file in *.jpg; do
    filebase=`basename $file`
    convert $file -quality 50 ${filebase}.new.jpg
done
```

Another alternative is to use Gimp in batch mode:

http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/

Comment: Yes, I do need loss-less. Very nice - thx for the Gimp link.

Answer (score 0):

The tool you want is called [jpegtran](http://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/). It's available in most Linux distributions and a Windows binary is also available. The command you want to use is:

```
jpegtran -copy none -progressive -outfile out_filename.jpg in_filename.jpg
```

You should easily be able to script this with a batch file or shell script to run on all your image files. Note that this may remove copyright notices and the like. If that's an issue, change `-copy none` to 
`-copy comments`.